# Spark: programm stuck when reading more than one line from a textfile?

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have this simple code Java code using Spark 2.1.2 running on a Mac with master set to local[2]:

```
JavaRDD<String> demands = javaSparkContext.textFile(DEMANDS, 10);
demands.map(this::extractDemand)
       .map(this::updateStatistics)
       .foreach(demandDecorator::decorate);
```

The decorator loads data via Spark sql and filters the dataset using a where()-clause and adds information to the demand object.

The strange thing is, if the text file contains only 1 line the program works perfectly. As soon as there is a second or more lines in the text file, the program hangs and does not finish, i.e. it is stuck at the "TaskSchedulerImpl" line in the log file.

In general I noticed, if I have one line less than set in "master" than it works, i.e. if master is set to 5 than it works with 4 lines in the text file. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the tail of the log file:

```
17/11/07 20:02:19 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 3 (show at DemandDecorator.java:64)
17/11/07 20:02:19 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
17/11/07 20:02:19 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
17/11/07 20:02:19 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 3 (MapPartitionsRDD[8] at show at OrderVehicleDataDecorator.java:64), which has no missing parents
17/11/07 20:02:19 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_4 stored as values in memory (estimated size 12.3 KB, free 2004.4 MB)
17/11/07 20:02:19 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_4_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 5.8 KB, free 2004.4 MB)
17/11/07 20:02:19 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_4_piece0 in memory on 127.0.0.1:59665 (size: 5.8 KB, free: 2004.6 MB)
17/11/07 20:02:19 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 4 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:996
17/11/07 20:02:19 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 1 missing tasks from ResultStage 3 (MapPartitionsRDD[8] at show at DemandDecorator.java:64)
17/11/07 20:02:19 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 3.0 with 1 tasks
```

I don't have a clue why this is happening. Does anyone have an idea what could be the problem?

Comment: simplify the code to get the minumum 'not working' code and update question

Comment: This is the minimum working code. As mentioned, if the text file contains x-1 lines than set master("local[x]") it works. Strange.

Comment: Ok, when I reduce the minPartition parameter to [no-of-cores] - 1 the program runs flawlessly. Is this somewhere documented?